# Make relative element appear before absolute element same container

Tags: html, css

I have two images inside a div. Same width/height and an effect on hover to display the secondary element. However, the secondary image is displaying before the first one, what is not the expected behavior.

The CSS:

```
.div-container {
    position: relative;
}

.div-container img.primary {
    position: relative;
}

.div-container img.secondary {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.div-container img.secondary:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="div-container">
    <img class="primary">
    <img class="secondary">
</div>
```

**The question:** I want to display the primary image first.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/A6y7Y/

Comment: z-index is what you are looking for!

Comment: I had try z-index on all elements but apparently didn't worked.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A6y7Y/2/

Comment: This link may help for you. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Comment: @rk rk actually I edited my code based on this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

For some reason, setting `opacity: 0` to the hovered image, made it appear first.
All I did was set the secondary image to `opacity: 0` and the container div on hover with `opacity: 1` (instead of the hovered image). I also included a `z-index` to both images with the secondary image with a higher index. Below the code I'm using, hope it could help someone in the future.

```
.div-container {
    position: relative;
}

.div-container img.primary {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

.div-container img.secondary {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 6;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.div-container:hover img.secondary {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `z-index` and change the values on the `:hover` effect or just easily switch the images. But what you should be looking for here is putting them on a single file and controlling the position of the background image with CSS like a Sprite. [Here is a good example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/basic-link-rollover-as-css-sprite/)

Comment: Hi Andre. z-index didn't worked and using sprites is not a solution since I don't have control over the images.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the css style of the primary and secondary css style and add z-index to the primary as 1 should resolve the issue

HTML

```
`<div class="div-container">
    <div class="primary">Layer1</div>
    <div class="secondary">Layer2</div>
</div>`
```

CSS

```
`.div-container {
    position: relative;
}
.div-container div{
    width:100px;`enter code here`
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.div-container .secondary {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}

.div-container .primary {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-index:1;
}

.div-container .primary:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}`
```

Comment: The code worked but it truncates the images next to it

Comment: can you show it with fiddle example so it will be better to understand clearly